# UIImagePickerController shows text in UpperCase Letters "USE_PHOTO" , "RETAKE" and Gallery Images "CAMERA_ROLL"?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9

I am using the following code

```
func pickerImage(type type : String , presentInVc : UIViewController , pickedListner : onPicked , canceledListner : onCanceled){

        self.pickedListner = pickedListner
        self.canceledListner = canceledListner

        let picker : UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.sourceType = type == CameraMode.Camera ? .Camera : .PhotoLibrary
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.allowsEditing = false
        presentInVc.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I've faced the same issue and the problem was, we need to set "AppleLanguages" user defaults to allow system frameworks to load localized strings in the same language that is set. I used the BundleLocalization library for localization and that was my main problem. Link: https://github.com/cmaftuleac/BundleLocalization

Issue link: [UIImagePickerController shows all text in weird capital case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40079928/uiimagepickercontroller-shows-all-text-in-weird-capital-case)

Thanks