# UIImagePickerController shows all text in weird capital case

Tags: ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, photo

I'm having an issue using UIImagePickerController, it works fine on my sample app and I've experience with this issue too. But for my current app, after supporting multi-language I'm having a weird issue. Image picker localization not working. That's not the main problem.

The main problem is all the text is shown in capital case in a weird way. Please check the attached screenshot.

[image]

This happens to iOS 8,9 and 10 all devices and simulator.

I'm wondering if anyone can help me.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: It would better if you put some code related to how you localized it

Comment: I just add Locatization to my project and use `NSLocalizedString(key, comment: "")` to localize my string files. For storyboard i've user Licalizable Strings file.

Comment: Issue is resolved now, the problem was we need to set "AppleLanguages" user defaults to allow system frameworks to load localized strings in the same language that is set using setLanguage. I used BundleLocalization library for localization. Link: https://github.com/cmaftuleac/BundleLocalization

Thanks